# iOS Track movement of ball shaped object in video

Tags: ios, objective-c, motion-detection

I am wondering if there are any good frameworks available that would allow me to:

1. Identify a "ball" object in a video. There will ALWAYS be a ball object, usually an identifiable color, but not always the same darkness, etc
2. Track the movement of that ball object over time. For example, I need to know how far it moves (x, y coordinates) in a 5 second period.
3. Take into consideration camera movement. If the user backs up, twitches, etc, I still need my x,y calculations to be accurate based on the new scale factor of the video frame.

Can anyone point me to a library that would get me started down this path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the OpenCV library. You might be asking too much, but that's probably your best bet.